# Safely tar compress a file while it is updating

Tags: linux, tar, gunzip

I need to compress a file on Linux using [tar](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_32.html) from a thread in a process. The file is getting updated like once in a second.

I am running the following command to do that from a separate process.

```
tar -cvzf /destination/compressed_files.tar.gz /directory/to/archive
```

It works well. No issues found. But, I have the following question.

**Primary question:**
I am trying to be a bit safer and more reliable with my code. Is the above way safe "in perspective of tar command". Does tar implicitly take care of the fact that the files is getting updated and it compresses whatever is possible? Does tar make a copy of the content internally?

**Secondary question:**
I found that following is a way to tar as well

```
    tar -cvzf /destination/compressed_files.tar.gz -C /destination /directory/to/archive
```

Looks like `-C` option changes the directory? Is it safer to use `-C` here?

Comment: When you say the source file is  being "updated", do you mean it is being appended to, or it is having its preexisting contents modified?

Comment: The source content is only getting appended with some lines. Existing content not modified. After some rigorous testing, I now see that tar gives an additional message stating "file changed as we read it". But that seems to be only a warning and it looks like `tar` gets what it is able to grab. Am I correct in my understand of how tar works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you will get depends on a bunch of factors, including the type of filesystem (e.g. NFS vs a local disk), the way the file is being written, and how much data is appended each time.

In the best case scenario, the writer has a local file open in append mode, and writes lines of text no longer than some internal buffer size.  In this case, you will probably not see any problems.  If the lines are very long, you may see partial lines.  If the file mode is not append, or the filesystem is NFS or something else unusual, you may see zeros or garbage values at the end of the file (because the file length was changed before the content).

In general, it would be better not to rely on this.  A typical approach is to "roll" the file every so often, closing the old one and starting to write a new one.  Then you can archive only "complete" files which the writer has closed (and perhaps renamed to indicate they are complete).